# OBSOLETE - SkillRep - experiment in computing a skill focused reputation

Tags: app, users, website, chrome-extensions, obsolete

**Update:** Now offline/closed.  See [the answer, below](https://stackapps.com/a/7902/7653).

Reputation, on the Stack Overflow Site, is mostly a measure of a user's contribution.

That's fine but sometimes, when looking at a user you encounter on SO, you're more interested in his skills.
You don't want a score coming from questions or polluted by a high-scoring answer to a trivial but very popular question.

**SkillRep** is both

**1.** [**a site**](https://dystroy.org/skillrep/) ranking all users with (a little) less pollution on scoring. The *About* section explains how the "skill rep" is computed.

[image]

**2.** [**an extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skillrep/mgacjhnogpfhjfdkbdpckjnlclgenblp) for Chrome displaying the rank and skill reputation of all users directly in the Stack Overflow site.

[image]

Incidentally it's written in Go. Curious coders might want to have a look at how querying the SE API or serving JSON can be done in Go (it's fairly simple).

*Obviously this shouldn't be taken too seriously.*

Comment: I am curious to know, Where are you getting the data for this ?

Comment: @Shyju I "just" query the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). As SkillRep is open-source, you may [have a look](https://github.com/Canop/skillrep/blob/master/core%2Fupdater.go).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry all, I closed the site.

This was taking way too much space on my server's hard disk and I felt the burden on SO servers was ridiculous for such a tiny amount of users (this never took off).

[The source](https://github.com/Canop/skillrep) is still available for anyone interested.